# Google Dialogflow Messenger Integrations not working

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration

I created a Dialogflow Integration. Then I copy the Script statements to my skeletal HTML.  The intent works at this point when I click the "Try it now' button; however, when I execute it on the web, I just get the prompt icon.  I do not get a prompt. It behaves as though I am working with an empty intent. The Intent works just fine in the dialogflwo interface.

Comment: Hi @Scott Bing, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.